# return string after a request to firebase in Unity / c#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone know how to return a value of a get to a Firebase Database after it is completed? 
I want for example to return the string "extracted.pl_superhit" to another class and it's an async process...

```
    public void LoadData_element(string player)
{

    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(DATA_URL);
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReferenceFromUrl(DATA_URL).GetValueAsync()
        .ContinueWith((task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                print("Falhou o Load dos dados");
            }
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                print("Cancelou o load dos dados");
            }
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot datasnap = task.Result;
                string pData = datasnap.GetRawJsonValue();
                var humidval = datasnap.Child(player).GetRawJsonValue();
                string test = humidval.ToString();
                print("x:" + test);
                Firebase_Database_Player extracted = JsonUtility.FromJson<Firebase_Database_Player>(test);
                print("Player_name:" + extracted.pl_name);
                print("Player_lfbar:" + extracted.pl_lfbar);
                print("Player_hit:" + extracted.pl_hit);
                print("Player_superhit:" + extracted.pl_superhit);
                print("Player_defend:" + extracted.pl_defend);
                print("Player_atuallife:" + extracted.pl_atuallife);
                print("Player_atualattack:" + extracted.pl_atualattack);

            }

        }));


}
```

thanks

Comment: Create a method that takes a method as a call back to set the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function async and await the necessary calls

```
public async Task<string> LoadData_element(string player) {

    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(DATA_URL);
    var reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReferenceFromUrl(DATA_URL);
    DataSnapshot datasnap = await reference.GetValueAsync()

    string pData = datasnap.GetRawJsonValue();
    var humidval = datasnap.Child(player).GetRawJsonValue();
    string test = humidval.ToString();
    print("x:" + test);
    Firebase_Database_Player extracted = JsonUtility.FromJson<Firebase_Database_Player>(test);
    print("Player_name:" + extracted.pl_name);
    print("Player_lfbar:" + extracted.pl_lfbar);
    print("Player_hit:" + extracted.pl_hit);
    print("Player_superhit:" + extracted.pl_superhit);
    print("Player_defend:" + extracted.pl_defend);
    print("Player_atuallife:" + extracted.pl_atuallife);
    print("Player_atualattack:" + extracted.pl_atualattack);

    return extracted.pl_superhit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   It worked! However, I needed to change the methods when I call it to async too, and after that it is excellent! I appreciated the helpfulness!